# Relation similarity calculation in sql (also called collaborative filtering user-user)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a kind of social network dataset where users follow other users.
The data is structured in one table like that:

```
from_user_id   to_user_id    event_date
100            201           2020-12-18 00:00:00
101            200           2020-12-18 00:00:00
102            200           2020-12-18 00:00:00
102            201           2020-12-18 00:00:00
103            201           2020-12-18 00:00:00
103            204           2020-12-18 00:00:00
106            201           2020-12-18 00:00:00
106            204           2020-12-18 00:00:00
106            205           2020-12-18 00:00:00
107            205           2020-12-18 00:00:00
```

given a list of user_ids stored in another table (called top_1000), I would like to retrieve the 3 other users from this list of 1000 who share the most 'followers' in common.

Sample top_1000 table:

```
user_id
200
201
202
203 
204
205
```

I have 0 idea on how to start with this one.... I guess a self join is probably needed though.

As we can see 100, 103 and 106 are following 201, but 106 also follows 204 and 205, therefore the output should be something like

```
to_user_id   suggested_user_id    rank     count
200          201                  1        1     
201          204                  1        2
201          206                  2        1
```

Comment: I'm not sure if sql is the right language for such comparisons. If you have just 1k users, then you have to do 999 comparison for the 1st user, 998 for the 2nd, and so on. You can see that the number of comparisons will quickly go off the scale.

Comment: your question is not clear  ..add  also a proper data sample and not only an expected  result  ..

Comment: How is "followers" defined?  It is not clear from the table you have shown.  What is "suggested_user_id"?  It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the original question.

Comment: thanks, it can indeed be done in a script doing collaborative filtering, but it can also be achieved by sql as Gordon hints at. 
I have updated my question with better sample data, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all pairs of users that have followers in common (assuming "following" is the "to" column) using a self join:

```
select f.from_user_id, f2.from_user_id as suggested_user_id, count(*) as followers_in_common
from follows f
     follows f2
     on f2.to_user_id = f.to_user_id and
        f2.from_user_id <> f.from_user_id
where exists (select 1 from top_1000 t where f.from_user_id = t.user_id) and
      exists (select 1 from top_1000 t where f2.from_user_id = t.user_id) 
group by f.from_user_id, f2.from_user_id;
```

The `where` clause limits the followers but not the followed based on your `top_1000` table.

You can then get the top three using window functions:

```
select ff.*
from (select f.from_user_id, f2.from_user_id as suggested_user_id, 
             count(*) as followers_in_common,
             row_number() over (partition by f.from_user_id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from follows f
           follows f2
           on f2.to_user_id = f.to_user_id and
              f2.from_user_id <> f.from_user_id
      where exists (select 1 from top_1000 t where f.from_user_id = t.user_id) and
            exists (select 1 from top_1000 t where f2.from_user_id = t.user_id) 
      group by f.from_user_id, f2.from_user_id
     ) ff
where seqnum <= 3;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that is a beautiful query. I'm not getting any result unfortunately (and my mysql version require inner join, it doesn't accept table name only for self join. I'm adding sample data to the question for easier understanding

Comment: ok it works by inverting to and from in most of the query:
select ff.*
from (
 select f.to_user_id, f2.to_user_id as suggested_user_id, count(*) as followers_in_common,
  row_number() over (partition by f.to_user_id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
 from follows f
 inner join follows f2
      on f2.from_id = f.from_id 
      and f2.to_id <> f.to_id
 where exists (select t.user_id from top_1000 t where f.to_user_id = t.user_id) and
       exists (select t.user_id from top_1000 t where f2.to_user_id = t.user_id) 
 group by f.to_user_id, f2.to_user_id
) ff
where seqnum <= 3;